# React.js integration with ASP MVC with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am new to React world, and I'm trying to integrate it in a new project that uses ASP MVC .net. 
I want to use React.js with the [create react app,](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/) not interested in the [React.net integration](https://reactjs.net/).

I have seen a couple [examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnFgGYooDCM) that don't use the CRA command, instead they configure the build set up themselves (webpack, babel, etc), I was trying that approach, but I'm worried that if the project grows I will lose track of updates, etc.

In that [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnFgGYooDCM), you need to add whatever the output of the webpack bundled file is into your index.cshtml.

```html
<div id="root"></div>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/React/dist/bundle.js"></script>
}
```

But when I use the CRA command I don't have access to that file during development, only when I build for production.

I'm a little lost here, what is the best way of achieving what I need with CRA without ejecting?

I really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do what you want (and I wanted too) with CRA and I believe the complexity you will end up after ejecting is too high to be manageable.

My starting point: a big ASP MVC application running an Angular.js front-end within a single MVC Controller/View (the default index page).
My goal: stop growing the Angular.js app and develop new functionality with React whenever possible, i.e. when it is independent of existing UI; let's call it new modules. I still need to keep everything within the same MVC app because it provides authentication and authorization among other things.

The solution: a custom (with respect to CRA) webpack build toolchain whose starting point is the [youtube example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnFgGYooDCM) you provided. Thanks to [this other tutorial](https://dev.to/dance2die/setting-up-a-react-environment-for-aspnet-mvc-44la), I have been able to add hot reload and after a few hours of trial and error I added loaders for css, images and fonts. The bundled result is for sure less optimal than the outcome of CRA, but it coexists with the old Angular.js so I believe it is good enough.

Here is some code.

webpack.config.js

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const PUBLIC_PATH = 'Scripts/react/dist';

module.exports = (env, arg) => {

    const isDevelopment = arg.mode === 'development';

    const fileLoaderName = file => {
        if (isDevelopment)
            return '[folder]/[name].[ext]';
        return '[folder]/[name].[ext]?[contenthash]';

    };

    return {
        entry: './app.js',
        watch: isDevelopment,
        devtool: isDevelopment ? 'source-map' : undefined,
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        'babel-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'eslint-loader',
                            options: {
                                fix: true
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: fileLoaderName,
                                publicPath: PUBLIC_PATH,
                                postTransformPublicPath: p => `__webpack_public_path__ + ${p}`
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot)$/i,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: fileLoaderName,
                                publicPath: PUBLIC_PATH,
                                postTransformPublicPath: p => `__webpack_public_path__ + ${p}`
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
            new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
            new BrowserSyncPlugin(),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "bundle.css" })
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
    }

};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react-app/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier":  ["error"],
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      { "allowTemplateLiterals": true }
    ]
  }
}
```

.prettierrc

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

package.json

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    ...
  },
```

There are still a few useful things that are missing and I plan to add in the future, like css modules and other css optimizations, but I think it's not going to be to difficult.